# Focusable EditText in ListView and Swipe to Dismiss

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, duplicates, ontouchlistener

I have a MainActivity, CustomListAdapter, customlistItem.xml, mainlayout.xml, SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java, SwipeDismissTouchListener.java.
I'm using a [this](https://github.com/romannurik/android-swipetodismiss) code(Swipe to Dismiss).

I want to make a focusable(editable) EditText in ListView & onItemClickListener ListView & Swipe to Dismiss ListView.

My Code works well focusable(editable) EditText in ListView & onItemClickListener ListView.
But didn't work the Swipe to Dismiss ListView.

If I make a new Item, then Swipe to Dismiss ListView works well, but Didn't work focusable(editable) EditText in ListView & onItemClickListener ListView.

I think there is a problem with TouchListener code.(dupplicated)

What am I Supposed to do?

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
footer.setOnClickListener(new View.onclickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    int id=0;
    String list = "new";
    String contents = "";

    myHelper = new myDBHelper(myListActivity.this);
    myadapter = new subMyListAdapter(myListActivity.this, R.layout.custom_edit_item, arrItem,myHelper);
    mainList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mainList.setAdapter(myadapter);

    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(mainList,
        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean canDismiss(int position) 
            {
                 return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) 
            {
                 for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) 
                 {
                       myadapter.remove(position);
                 }
                       myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
        });
        mainList.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        mainList.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
        sqlDB = myHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clearTBL;", null);
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO clearTBL(list, contents) VALUES ('"
                    + list + "' , '" + "');");
        arrItem.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {
                id = cursor.getInt(0);
                list = cursor.getString(1);
                contents = cursor.getString(2);
                subMyItem item = new subMyItem(id, list, contents);
                arrItem.add(item);
        }
        myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
mainList.addFooterView(footerViewLayout, null, true);
    mainList.setAdapter(myadapter);
    mainList.setDivider(null);

SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(mainList,
        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean canDismiss(int position) 
            {
                 return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) 
            {
                 for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) 
                 {
                       myadapter.remove(position);
                 }
                       myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
        });
```

**subMyListAdapter.java**

```
...
holder.tvItem.setOnTouchListener(test);
conv.setOnTouchListener(test);
...
View.OnTouchListener test=  new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (view instanceof EditText) 
        {
            tvItem = (EditText) view;
            tvItem.setFocusable(true);
            tvItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            try
            {
                openPositon = Integer.parseInt(tvItem.getTag().toString()); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
            if(sPosition!=null)
            {
                int pos = Integer.parseInt(sPosition);
                myHelper = new myDBHelper(context);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                subMyItem user = arraySrc.get(pos);
                int a = user.id;
                String update = "UPDATE clearTBL SET list='" + tvItem.getText().toString()+ "' WHERE id=" + a + ";";
                try
                {
                    sqlDB.execSQL(update);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sqlDB.close();

                myListActivity.arrItem.get(pos).list = tvItem.toString();
            }

        } else 
        {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
            view.requestFocus();
            UserHolder holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.tvItem.clearFocus();
            holder.tvItem.setMovementMethod(null);
            holder.tvItem.setFocusable(false);
            holder.tvItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

            try
            {
                sPosition = tvItem.getTag().toString(); 
            }
            catch
            (Exception e)
            {}
            if(sPosition!=null)
            {
                int pos = Integer.parseInt(sPosition);
                myHelper = new myDBHelper(context);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                subMyItem user = arraySrc.get(pos);
                int a = user.id;
                String update = "UPDATE clearTBL SET list='" + tvItem.getText().toString()+ "' WHERE id=" + a + ";";
                try
                {
                    sqlDB.execSQL(update);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sqlDB.close();
                myListActivity.arrItem.get(pos).list = tvItem.toString();
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
};
```

**Manifest**

```
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
/*android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" didn't works for Focusable EditText*/
...
```